# How to use SqlCommand and SqlDataReader to return a Json result in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to use a SQL query in `SqlCommand` and I'd like to see the complete result set that is returned from SQL Server database, and return Json format after that.

So here is the code in controller:

```
public ActionResult GetAllSummary()
{
    string connectionString ="Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;Integrated Security=True";  
    string query = "SELECT v.date, v.name, v.numbers FROM view as v GROUP BY v.date,v.mane,v.numbers ORDER BY v.date,v.mane,v.numbers";

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        try {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            // In this part below, I want the SqlDataReader  to 
            // read all of the records from database returned, 
            // and I want the result to be returned as Array or 
            // Json type, but I don't know how to write this part.

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

                foreach(int i in reader)
                     // this line below was the code I wrote before. 
                     // But since my query returns multiple 
                     // types (datetime, string, decimal, etc..), 
                     // I don't know what C# command I can use to return
                     // the results in foreach loop. Or say I even don't 
                     // need a for/foreach loop.
                     result.Add(reader.GetValue(i));

                return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex.Message;
            return View(error);
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Anyone can help me to make this work? I will be greatly appreciated.

Kevin

Comment: what is the error you get, try putting a breakpoint inside while loop, where you able to reach to that point.

Comment: Your using `return Json(...` inside the `foreach` loop so it immediately exits the method and returns a result as soon as the first value of first row is read.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this does't compile at all. What is supposed to mean _foreach(int i in reader)_ ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually it isn't inside the foreach.  He's just single the single command version of it rather than the block.  It is, however, inside the while loop.

Comment: His SQL is inefficient as he is grouping by the same columns he is selecting with no aggregate, so he should have used DISTINCT instead.

Comment: Step 1. Move the code for reading to a separate service (it should not be inside a controller). Step 2. Create a model with properties `Date`, `Name` and `Numbers` and inside the `while` loop, initialize an instance of your model, set its properties and add it to a collection and finally return a collection of your model. Step 3. Call the service in your controller to get `List<yourModel>` and then return it to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class data {
  public DateTime date {get;set;}
  public string name {get;set;}
  public int numbers {get;set;}
}
public ActionResult GetAllSummary()
{
    string connectionString ="Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;Integrated Security=True";  
    string query = "SELECT DISTINCT v.date, v.name, v.numbers FROM view as v ORDER BY v.date,v.name,v.numbers";

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        try {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            // In this part below, I want the SqlDataReader  to 
            // read all of the records from database returned, 
            // and I want the result to be returned as Array or 
            // Json type, but I don't know how to write this part.

            while(reader.Read())
            {
                List<data> result = new List<data>();
                var d=new data();
                d.date=reader[0]; // Probably needs fixing
                d.name=reader[1]; // Probably needs fixing
                d.numbers=reader[2]; // Probably needs fixing
                result.Add(data);
            }

            reader.Close();
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex.Message;
            return View(error);
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

or

```
public class data {
  public DateTime date {get;set;}
  public string name {get;set;}
  public int numbers {get;set;}
}
public ActionResult GetAllSummary()
{
    string connectionString ="Data Source=...;Initial Catalog=...;Integrated Security=True";  
    string query = "SELECT DISTINCT v.date, v.name, v.numbers FROM view as v ORDER BY v.date,v.name,v.numbers";

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        try {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            var dt=new DataTable();
            dt.Load(myDataReader);
            List<DataRow> result=dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
            reader.Close();
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex.Message;
            return View(error);
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

or (just the interesting part):

```
var dt=new DataTable();
dt.Load(myDataReader);
object[] result = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1];

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++) {
    result[i] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! In the third method, how can I init arr[] or what type of arr[] would be?

Comment: @QIWENHU Sorry, the reference to arr[] was supposed to be be a reference to result[].  I've updated the answer to reflect the correction.

Comment: Alright, actually all methods worked and the third one applied to my situation. Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension:

```
public static string ExecuteToJson(this SqlCommand cmd)
{
    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
    }

    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);

            List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
            Dictionary<string, object> row;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                {
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                }
                rows.Add(row);
            }

            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rows);
        }
    }
}
```

and the usage:

```
string connectionString = "** connstr **";
string query = "SELECT * FROM `table`";

try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            string json = command.ExecuteToJson(); 
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```